# On the product of two normalised functions

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions

Say I have a normalised function $f(x)$ over some domain $\{-\xi, \xi\}$.

Obviously:

- $\int_{-\xi} ^\xi f\,\mathrm{d}x = 1$
- $\int_{-\xi} ^\xi f\,\mathrm{d}x \cdot \int_{-\xi} ^\xi f\,\mathrm{d}x = 1$

What information can I gather about the integral of the overlap integral for this function:

$$\int_{-\xi} ^\xi f^\ast f\,\mathrm{d}x = ?$$

Or in general about the product of two normalised functions:
$$\int_{-\xi} ^\xi f^\ast g\,\mathrm{d}x = ?$$

In quantum mechanics, if $f$ and $g$ are wavefunctions of the same operator, they belong in the same Complete Orthonormal basis set (CONS) and then I have:
$$\int_{-\xi} ^\xi f^\ast g\,\mathrm{d}x \leq 1 \quad \text{with} \quad =1 \quad \text{iff}\quad f=g$$

Is this a property of CONS only? I cannot apply it to a general normalised function?

Comment: When in quantum mechanics do you need to work with $L^1$ norms (ofc you didn't take the modulus, but still)?

Comment: well it's $L^2$ norm but also the function of interest is the wavefunction $\psi$ and the normalisation requires $ \int |\psi|^2 =1$. I was a bit sloppy about the details, I just wanted to justify my intuition and the reasoning for the more general question about products of normalised functions.

Comment: I meant in your first lines. I was unsure if you were asking about how $L^1$ norms can tell you something about $L^2$ norms (again, you didn't normalize in the first equation).

Comment: Ah ok then yes, what you said. What do $L^1$ norms tell me about $L^2$ norms

Comment: Not much, unfortunately. Even on a bounded domain (say of measure $A$), you actually get that $\|f\|_{L^1}\leq \sqrt{A}\|f\|_{L^2}$ via Cauchy-Schwarz. So, the information comes in reverse. If the domain is unbounded, then you no longer even get a space inclusion.

Comment: @SuperCiocia The first and second comments to this post illustrate why it is so, so important to include all the relevant details. Learn to avoid [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).